# Sybase Connection String With Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string, sybase, windows-authentication, sap-ase

Currently we are using below connection string to connect through Sybase with some particular user credentials, using ASP.NET 4.0.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MySybaseDatabase" 
        connectionString="DataSource=dbo;Port=5010;UID=userName;PWD=Password;" 
        providerName="Sybase.Data.AseClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But here we want to use Windows Authentication. So how to change connection string so that user credentials of windows logged in user will be used.

Answer (score 0):

All will be same just use "`Integrated Security=SSPI;" instead of user name and password